# Why do all the Joys and Jennys look the same?

Tags: pokemon

I recall mention in the anime that all of the Nurse Joys are cousins, and that all the Officer Jenny's are cousins. I have also read mention that Joy and Jenny are their family names, explaining the matched names.

Has there ever been an explanation as to why all of the Jennys or Joys look identical?

[image: Officer Jennys]

[image: Nurse Joys]

Comment: http://pokemon.wikia.com/wiki/Officer_Jenny

Comment: They don't all look the same. http://i33.photobucket.com/albums/d56/Magus6666/Other/Joy2.jpg

Comment: She's wearing a different outfit, but there is no discernible difference between her and any of the other Joys otherwise.

Comment: But sure, let's keep concerning ourselves with pedantry instead of the fact that the same model is clearly re-used throughout hundreds of episodes.

Comment: And she's black.

Comment: being tanned !== being black. as i recall, that one lived on a beach.

Comment: This is racist. They look nothing alike. To Joy, *we* all look alike.

Comment: Her skin tone is well beyond what you'd expect from someone who is merely tanned. Admittedly, I'm basing this on my knowledge of dark-skinned characters found elsewhere in the show and on other anime.

Comment: fine. should i update the question to ask why every one except the one that lives on the beach looks identical beyond having different eyelash lengths? is that accurately pedantic enough for you?

Comment: Legitimately, Jenny and Joy are both family names and not first names.

Comment: Are you concerned with a thematic explanation, or a mechanical explanation?

Comment: Maybe, they are clones created by Team Rocket to keep eyes on their rivals.

Comment: I felt my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive, drawing from both the anime and real life. Is there anything else you'd want to see before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 20):

### Jenny

In-universe, all of the Officer Jennys are indeed **cousins**. They merely happen to all look like each other, dress identically and work in the same profession. Ash [puts this down](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) to a [strong family resemblance](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UncannyFamilyResemblance) (warning, TV Trope links!)

> **Ash:** *Officer Jenny!*
>
> **Jenny:** *Huh? Have we met before? Your face doesn't look familiar.*
>
> **Ash:** *We met you back in Viridian City, remember?*
>
> **Jenny:** *Oh, you mean one of the other Jennys. My cousins.*
>
> **Ash:** *Cousin?*
>
> **Jenny:** ***My cousins are all police officers. All of us look identical plus we're all called Jenny.***
>
> [shows photo of nine identical Jennys in police uniforms]
>
> **Ash:** *Talk about a family resemblance*
>
> <sub><sup>[Here Comes the Squirtle Squad](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP012)</sup></sub>

---

Interestingly, it would appear that the term 'Jenny' may be a family name, or possibly even a title since we meet at least one young Jenny in training ([Marble](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Marble_(DP059))) in [Luxray Vision!](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP059) that has a first name other than Jenny.

> **Marble:** *That's why Jenny Trainee Number One, me, came to investigate you!*
>
> **Ash:** *You mean you're...*
>
> **Dawn:** [interrupting] *Number one?*
>
> **Marble:** *Right! ...  The name's Marble, super-duper ace detective!*

---

### Joy

The name Joy appears to be a surname, rather than a forename. In [Drifloon in the Wind](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP028) we meet the [daughters of an older Nurse Joy](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Marnie_and_Paige) who plan to become Nurse Joys themselves. The family resemblance between mother and daughters is extremely striking.

> **Ash:** *You girls are so nice*
>
> **Marnie:** *We're going to be 'Nurse Joys', just like mom!*
> ...
> **Marnie:** *My name is Marnie Lynette Francis Joy*
>
> **Peach:** *And I'm Paige Francis Lynette Joy.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Drifloon On the Wind!](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DP028)</sup></sub>

---

Out of universe, it's worth noting that both 'Jenny' and 'Joy' are plays on the Japanese words for **Constable** ([巡査 - junsa](http://nugalis.com/japanese/vocabulary/word/4009-junsa-policepoliceman/)) and **Female Doctor** ([女医 - joi](https://translate.google.co.uk/#auto/ja/lady%20doctor))

Comment: I also think that out of universe, the joke was made because in the original games every Pokémon Center looked the same inside, so everywhere you go you would end up meeting the "same" npc nurse "Joy".

Comment: @SPArchaeologist - I thought that a bit too obvious to include in the answer :-)

Comment: so, your explanation for why they all look alike is because they all happen to look alike?

Comment: @KutuluMike - There's a *family resemblance*.

Comment: I'm at a loss why this is attracting downvotes. If anyone wants to chime in, please feel free.

Comment: @Valorum DVs could be from essentially re-stating that the appearance is because they are cousins... the OP knew that.  Not sure if the DVs came before or after your numerous edits. Just shot in the dark. I gave it a +1...

Comment: a family resemblance might explain a few looking similar, not hundreds looking identical.

Comment: I always figured they were actually clones, and using "cousin" was a polite way to avoid the subject.

Comment: @vynsane - All of the explanations are simply retcons. The real reason is that it's an in-joke based on the fact that the game sprites were all identical.

Comment: I think the link for Marble is not correct. The linked page is about a spherical item.

Comment: @AaronFranke - Sorted. It was the right link when it was created, but they've moved the goalposts :-)

Answer (score 5):

Identical, huh?

[image: What your eyes don't see is very clear to me - Brock]

In all seriousness though, Brock has stated in at least one or two episodes that there are subtle differences between them. You just have to know what to look for ;)
In one instance, he says that he can tell apart two Nurse Joys because the length of their eyelashes is slightly different.
The only differences noticeable to anyone besides Brock are the colour of the plus on their nursing cap (In Joy's case) or the badge on their officer cap (In Jenny's case).

As to *why* they look so similar, I'd have to find an official source to be certain, but it's supposed to be an homage to the games, because every nurse in the Pokemon Centres and every officer running around used the same character model. So in the anime they made them all identical.
But as far as I know, there's no in-universe explanation, and at this point there's no reason to believe there ever will be.

Comment: Either this needs to explain some of the differences or explain why they are so close to being identical that they only have tiny differences.

Comment: In one instance, he says that he can tell  apart two Nurse Joys because the length of their eyelashes is slightly different. The only differences noticeable to anyone besides Brock are the colour of the plus on their nursing cap (In Joy's case) or the badge on their officer cap (In Jenny's case).

Comment: As to _why_ they look so similar, I'd have to find an official source to be certain, but it's supposed to be an homage to the games, because every nurse in the Pokemon Centres and every officer running around used the same character model. So in the anime they made them all identical.

Comment: But as far as I know, there's no in-universe explanation, and at this point there's no reason to believe there ever will be.

Comment: I always thought the in-universe explanation was that they were cousins. That was enough for me. You might say cousins aren't identical, but they can look very similar. Combine that with doing your hair and outfit the same way (I'm going to assume its a job requirement for them) and the lack of fine feature details in the anime and you wouldn't be able to tell the difference. I even saw a brain games episode where they swapped two guys who were similar looking out by pretending to drop a pen at a sign-in. 90% of the people didn't notice the difference. I think the game homage is also correct.

Comment: @Dalton: Change-blindness goes beyond that... they regularly run tests where people change race and sex and people still don't notice. :)

Comment: Right. I was running out of characters, but you're correct. So I think it's a safe bet to say that Brock is right and they are all different, we just see them the same.